# Path to file is modified by another view controller

Tags: objective-c, path, documentsdirectory

I have 2 view controllers that send requests to a web service.
Once the data is received, data is saved to files in the Document folder.

These are the 2 VC:

Live_VC:

```
#import "FV_Live_ViewController.h"

@interface FV_Live_ViewController ()
@end

@implementation FV_Live_ViewController

NSArray  *paths;
NSString *documentsDirectory;
NSString *path;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

paths              = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];

[self sendRequest];    // first request of data ("Live" data)
}

- (void)sendRequest {
// other code

// request of "Live" data
[urlRequest startWithCompletion:^(URLRequest *request, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        // other code

        NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"months.plist"];   
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];    // path = "...\months.plist"

        // second request of data (monthly data) if months.plist doesn't exists
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: path]) {
            [self sendMonthRequest];
        }
    }
}];
}    

- (void)sendMonthRequest {

[urlRequest startWithCompletion:^(URLRequest *request, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL success) {            
    if (success) {
        // other code

        [monthlyArray writeToFile: path atomically:YES];    // path should be "...\months.plist" while it is "...\yesterday.plist"
    }
}];
}

@end
```

Today_VC:

```
#import "FV_Today_ViewController.h"

@interface FV_Today_ViewController ()
@end

@implementation FV_Today_ViewController

NSArray  *paths;
NSString *documentsDirectory;
NSString *path;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

paths              = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];

[self sendRequest];        // first call of "sendRequest" to get today data
}

- (void)sendRequest {
//  other code

// request of "Today" data
[urlRequest startWithCompletion:^(URLRequest *request, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL success) {
    if (success) {       
        //  other code

        NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"today.plist"];
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];    // path = "...\today.plist"

        [dataDictionary writeToFile: path atomically:YES];      // save data to today.plist

        // second call of "sendRequest" to get yesterday data only if yesterday.plist doesn't already exists)           
        filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yesterday.plist"];
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];    // path = "...\yesterday.plist"
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
            [self sendRequest];
    }
}];
}

@end
```

In each VC I'm using an NSString ("path") to store the path but the problem is that in the "sendMonthRequest" method (Live_VC) the value of the path is the value set in the other VC (Today_VC).
How can it be possible ? How can the value of an NSString in the first VC be changed by the second VC ?

Thanks,
Corrado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this result because you made "path" a global variable by putting it at the top of the file. Surround it by curly braces, and then it will be a normal ivar,

```
@implementation FV_Today_ViewController {

NSArray  *paths;
NSString *documentsDirectory;
NSString *path;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know that by putting the var inside implementation file without bracket the var becomes global. I thought that a var declared in the implementation was private and that to share a var I needed to define it in the interface and than import the interface in the file where you need to access it. It's too easy to put it in the .m without bracket ...  Am I missing something ? Would you be so kind to clarify it ? Thanks, Corrado

Comment: @Corrado, it's true that if you add ivars in the implementation file, they're "private" (nothing is truly private in objective-c), and if you want other classes to be able to access an ivar, you should put it in the interface; you're understanding of that is correct. But, if you create a global variable, it doesn't matter which file you put it in, it will be available to any class that also declares that variable (like you did in both your classes). You do need to pay attention to those curly braces.